# how to combine rows with a key and keep the highest value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe with several rows and several columns and I need to keep the values from the other columns a,b,c by combining it into a single row of the corresponding key.

```
Key, ColA, ColB, Colc
111  0     12    0
111  12    0     0
111  0     0     12
222  12    0     0
222  0     0     12
```

and the output I want is

```
key, ColA, ColB, ColC
111  12    12    12
222  12    0     12
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to erase duplicate rows on bases of key column?

Comment: I want to keep the values of colA, colB and colC, in one row. The information on these columns are spread on multiple rows so they will need to be erased with keeping that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the `max` of each group:

```
>>> df.groupby('Key', as_index=False).max()

   Key  ColA  ColB  Colc
0  111    12    12    12
1  222    12     0    12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby()` to get the max value :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Key' : [111, 111, 111, 222, 222], 'ColA' : [0, 12, 0, 12, 0], 'ColB' : [12, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'ColC' : [0, 0, 12, 0, 12]})

print(df.groupby(by='Key', as_index = False).max())

# Output :
#    Key  ColA  ColB  ColC
# 0  111    12    12    12
# 1  222    12     0    12
```

Comment: Use `as_index=False` to avoid `reset_index`.

Comment: @Corralie Thanks! I edited the answer with ``as_index=False``